# restrict acces to a application facebbok only to my friends

Tags: facebook

how to restrict access to only a facebook application to my friends.
in this case by "facebook connect " without having to use the "sandbox"

I know it must allow only the id of his friends but technically how it goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your list of friends by querying `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`, using your user access token (not the app token). Facebook will return a JSON array of your friends. You can read more info here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You can then iterate through the JSON array and store a list in your server, e.g. in java:

```
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(txtResponse);
    ArrayList<String> myFriends = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
        myfriends.add (response.data[i].id);
    }
    // store the list somewhere
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // something went wrong. 
}
```

On your client side, you can get the user id in javascript. I'm writing the ajax call in jquery just to be brief. You can use plain javascript.

```
if(FB.getSession() != null) {
    var session = FB.getSession();
    if (session.uid===undefined)
       session = session.session;
    $.post("login", {id:session.uid}, function (response) {
        // you do here whatever you want based on the server decision to allow access or not.
    });
}
```

Of course, there will be a servlet responding that ajax post that will compare the id with the ones in myFriends list.

PS1: I wrote this on top of my head, so there may be typos/errors, but you get the idea.

PS2: Instead of the graph api, you can use also fql. More info here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: hi Aleadam. can you do this for me? if es for how much?

Comment: Sorry, wrong guy. I'm just an amateur coder, so I would not dare to charge for doing it. Many, including myself, will be happy to help you do it if you like. Also, please consider to mark the question as answered or delete it if you are only interested in hiring somebody.